# How to float Select2 Placeholder?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Im using Select2 in html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $progControl = $(".destination").select2({
    placeholder: "Destination(s)"
  });
})
```

```css
.custom-select {
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select name="destinations" id="destinations" class="custom-select destination" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Sample 1</option>
  <option value="2">Sample 2</option>
  <option value="3">Sample 3</option>
  <option value="4">Sample 4</option>
</select>
```

currently the Placeholder is inside the select box, 
how to make the Placeholder floating above the select box when Im in focus and option is selected? appreciated any help
thank you

Comment: Something like this? https://propeller.in/components/select2.php

Comment: @MoshFeu It seems that the link is broken, can't open the link

Comment: Well, I can. I don't know why it's not working for you. What are you get?

Comment: @MoshFeu it shows me this: This site can’t be reached
propeller.in’s server IP address could not be found.
Try running Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: Strange.. I don't know what to tell you. Maybe this website blocked by your network. Try its github page: https://github.com/digicorp/propeller/tree/master/components/select2

Comment: @MoshFeu I don't know why the site is blocked in my network :( Im going to the github link instead

Comment: @MoshFeu the propeller component is for Bootstrap 3 only, unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I wrote a [plugin](https://github.com/moshfeu/select2-placeholder-transition) special for you that does this (I hope). So you can use it like the snippet bellow.

Let me know what do you think.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $progControl = $(".destination").select2PlaceholderTransition({
    placeholder: 'Destination(s)',
    allowClear: true
  });
});
```

```css
.input-wrapper {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.custom-select {
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/moshfeu/select2-placeholder-transition/25a7a45569bc417b3332f75db317aa53e1e37927/select2-placeholder-transition.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moshfeu/select2-placeholder-transition/32f8cf2dfccc69a4822fa9c884bc6234a2b3ca05/select2-placeholder-transition.js"></script>

<div class="input-wrapper">
  <select name="destinations" id="destinations" class="custom-select destination" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Sample 1</option>
    <option value="2">Sample 2</option>
    <option value="3">Sample 3</option>
    <option value="4">Sample 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, man, appreciate this wonderful help, but I still have a question about this, when I put everything in place, and page is refreshed the placeholder automatically slide up to the top, not at the initial position

Comment: Is the select has selected value? If so, the logic is that the label goes up when the `select` has value.

Comment: I did exactly like the example no selected value but the placeholder always slides up, pushed by this css


.select2-container.select2-container--with-selected + label {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

Comment: `.select2-container--with-selected` class is added only if there are selected values - in my example there are no selected values by default so the placeholder is in the right place. Do you have a public URL for your project so I could try to debug it?

Comment: it's weird, I put the sample code on Codepen and it works, but wrong in my localhost :(

Comment: Can you public your localhost online so I could try to debug it?

Comment: I just found this behaviour on my localhost too! and I pushed a fix to the [rypo](https://github.com/moshfeu/select2-placeholder-transition), please take the newest version and let me know if everything cool..

Comment: it works now man, I thank you so much for this, but before that would you mind to explain me what's wrong with previous code? so I can learn from it.

Comment: My pleasure ☺ The problem was that the check was if the select has value (`!!$elem.val()`) but in multiple select the value is not a string but an array. So the check need to be also if the array is not empty (`!!$elem.val().length`).